# Switching from local to thor cluster in ECL IDE

Tags: hpcc, hpcc-ecl

I'm trying to switch to the thor cluster in the ECL IDE, but thor isn't available in the drop down menu. Is it a mistake I made during installation? Does anyone anything about this?

Comment: what version of HPCC and IDE?

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be a problem in HPCC Cluster (i.e Dali is down).
If the cluster is ok and you have connectivity you should have this:

[image]

If you cannot connect to it:

[image]

**Possible causes**:

- Once I had a similar problem when Dali process was down. I could reach cluster via 8010 ecl-watch but ECL-IDE was showing only local & hthor.
- Or maybe you had connectivity when you started ECLIDE and somehow lost it.

**Suggestions**:

- Investigate all relevant services in your cluster. If required start them.
- Check if other colleagues in your same network has similar problems.
- Restart HPCC Cluster.
- Install latest version of IDE...